# Attain a tally of a column of a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I have a 2d array data. And would like to attain a tally every time the jth iteration is a 1.
Where i = rows and j = columns. 
How do I go about doing this without a for loop?

Conceptually something like this:

```
for r in range(row):
    if(data[r][j] == 1)
        amount += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follow:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 1]])
j = 1
np.sum(a[:, j] == 1)
```

will give you 2 as a result
, while `np.sum(a[:, 0] == 1)` will give 1

If as mentioned in your comment you want to use a condition on multiple arrays, you can use `np.logical_and(condition1, condition2)`:

```
np.sum(np.logical_and(a[:, 0] == 1, b[:, 0] == 2))
```

Comment: is it possible to include a second condition?
for example: np.sum(arrayB = 2  and a[:, 0] == 1)

Comment: @user you can use np.logical_and(a[:, 0] == 1, b[:, 0] == 2)

Answer (score 0):

I interprete this question such that you want to iterate over both, rows and columns, and add 1 to `amount` for each entry in data that is 1. This can be done without looping as follows.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.ones((6,8))
amount = data[data == 1].sum()
print amount
```

If instaead, you fix one column `j`, and only want the amount in this column:

```
import numpy as np
j=7
data = np.ones((6,8))
amount = data[:,j][data[:,j]==1].sum()
print amount
```

Comment: I want to iterate through each row of a specific column j.